# Partially std::move a vector? Or how to split without new memory allocation?

Tags: c++11, move, move-semantics

When we move `std::vector` we just steal its content. So this code:

```
std::vector<MyClass> v{ std::move(tmpVec) };
```

will not allocate new memory, will not call any of constructors of `MyClass`.

But what if I want to split a temporary vector? In theory, I could steal the content as we did before and distribute it among new vectors. In practice I can't do this. The best so far solution I found is to use [`std::move()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) from `<algorithm>` header. But here the `operator new` will be called for every new vector. Additionally, move constructor (if available) will be called for every element we move.

What else can I do (c++17 counts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In theory, I could steal the content as we did before and distribute it among new vectors.

No, you cannot.

A memory allocation cannot be broken up into multiple memory allocations. At least, not without doing multiple memory allocations, then copying/moving the elements from the original into those separate pieces.

You cannot create separate `vector`s that have different storage without actually copying/moving the elements to those different memory buffers. You can of course take separate ranges of that `vector` and do whatever you can with such ranges (iterator/pointer pairs, `gsl::span`, etc). But each range would always be referencing elements ultimately owned by the source `vector`; they cannot independently own subranges of a `vector`.

Comment: By theory, I mean the following: a vector is basically a couple of pointers to the memory begin and end. So theoretically, we could specify any pointers as begin/end from this range to the new vector without the necessity to allocate. Of course, the old one should be invalidated. I don't see the reason why we can't do this (again - theoretically. Because the holy standard doesn't provide the way to do it).

Comment: "A memory allocation cannot be broken up into multiple memory allocations." - that confuses me. Why not?

Comment: @nikitablack: But the `vector` you're creating would allocate memory for itself. The two iterator constructor of `vector` does not *adopt* given memory; it *allocates* its own memory.

Comment: @nikitablack: "*again - theoretically. Because the holy standard doesn't provide the way to do it*" If the standard doesn't allow it, then it's not a valid theory. If you're asking about what `vector` can do, then what it must do first is conform to the standard. Otherwise, it's not a `vector`. If you're asking about what a `vector` ***like*** type can do, that's a different question. The answer is still pretty much "no", but for more complex reasons.

Comment: yes, you're right. The question was what can I do to steal a part of the memory. But now I see that even if I could do it, the other part should be deallocated which is not possible. Sad, but yeah, I'm accepting your "`No, you cannot`" answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `span` class that stores two pointers, and does not own the data between them.  It can have many vector-like operations on it.

It should also support slicing itself (without allocation) into sub components.

You can write an `shared_span` class that has both those two pointers, and a `shared_ptr` which represents (possibly shared) ownership of the underlying buffer.  It should support the operations of `span`, except functions returning `span` (like `without_front(std::size_t count=1)`) should instead return `shared_span` (with shared ownership).

You can write a move constructor from `vector` to `shared_span` easily.  You may even be able to write a function from `shared_span` to `vector` with a special allocator that doesn't allocate until it grows.  Making that fully portable would be very difficult.

If it is possible (I am uncertain), you could take a `std::vector`, move its storage into a `shared_ptr<std::vector>`, feed that to an allocator, build two `std::vector<T, special_allocator>`s that use that memory, and do what you want.

But you could just replace your request for `vector` doing this with code that consume a `shared_span`.  `shared_span` could even have a concept of extra "dead" memory before/after the buffer it is using, giving it performance approaching `std::vector`.

There is a span in the `gsl` library you could possibly use.  I am unaware of a publicly available `shared_span`.